# Jquery traversing problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have a page with multiple instances that contain of the following code:

```
<div class="company">
  <a class="toggle" id="<%= "tgl#{company.id}" -%>">...</a>
  <p>...other stuff...</p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="expand_me companyExpand" id="">...
```

This code shows the beginning of each 'panel'. When the user clicks on the `.toggle`, I need the `.expand_me` to toggle open using Jquery.

Here's my code so far - it isn't working and I think it's due to a traversing problem.

```
$( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children(".expand_me").toggle( "blind", {}, 500, callback );
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You do not show where the `a` tag closes... is the `p` and the divs included in the `a` or on the same level ?

Comment: I is probably not a traversal problem, but how you call `toggle`. Have a look at the parameters it takes: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ Also not that links that don't have an `href` attribute won't be rendered as links. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/csgHQ/

Comment: @Felix, the OP is using the jquery UI extended version at http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/

Comment: @GabyAkaG.Petrioli - I've edited my answer to include the `<a>` tag more accurately.

Comment: @Gaby: Oh.... thanks. Forgot to look at that.... but now I also see the `jquery-ui` tag :D NVM

Comment: Given, the closing `a` tag, your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/csgHQ/1/ Make sure you have a callback or remove the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most safe way would be

```
$( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.company').find('.expand_me').toggle( "blind", {}, 500, callback );
  return false; // to avoid following the actual link
});
```

Also note that you must have defined a method `callback` in order to use this. (*or use the name of the function you want, instead*)
I am saying this in case you just copy/pasted the code from the jquery examples.

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/duAue/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".expand_me").slideToggle( 500, callback );
});
```

Comment: Gaby's version worked for me. Thank you for this, I appreciate how succinct it is. +1.